# To redirect from one page to another page in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

Im new to WPF. I want to redirect from one form to another form by clicking on a button. Is this possible in WPF. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

Forms in WPF are referred as Windows. Window.Show will let you open/show the new window.
For example: Lets assume there are two windows WindowOne and WindowTwo both are derived from Window. so the code would look like:

```
WindowOneButton_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   WindowTwo windowTwo = new WindowTwo(); 
   //this will open your child window
   windowTwo .Show();
   //this will close parent window. windowOne in this case
   this.Close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and there are various ways of achieving this...

If you create a new WPF project in VS it will create a MainWindow. Add a new window, by default it will be called Window1. If you place a button on MainWindow and under the click event of the button put the following code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 NewWindow = new Window1();
    NewWindow.Show();
}
```

This will show Window1.

Basically you are creating a new instance of the Window1 class.

Comment: Thank you for the code..,but it is throwing some error like "the page does not contain a definition for Show().., what to do?

Comment: Make sure that the second Window is actually a window and not a Page or something like that... one way to check that this is done is if you go to the Window1.xaml.cs file and check the class definition it should look like "public partial class Window2 : Window", if it doesnt, then it isnt a standard WPF window.

Comment: I used a page for the second one.,what should i do if it is a Page to redirect?

Comment: A page is typically shown in a frame control or navigation window - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/51860d02-2217-45c8-8f49-49771e7e002d/ - I would go the window route for now until you are more comfortable with WPF and then you can branch out to Pages and UserControls etc...

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned method will work for windows only.
If we have to do page redirection then need to use the below method. This will work smoothly.
**NavigationService.Navigate(new LatestActiveUsers());**

The main benefit of this method is you can choose the page from another folder also.
**NavigationService.Navigate(new Settings.LatestActiveUsers());**